# Restricting selecting same item for multiple dropdownlists mvc5

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 dropdownlists in my view which has same elements in every ddl. I have used separate viewbags for each ddl although elements are same. Where im struggling is i want to restrict user by selecting an element in a particular ddl which has already been chosen by him in another ddl. Below i have put the partialview. How to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ItemTemplate"))
    {

         <div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;"><b>Attribute 01</b> <b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Atribute1, new SelectList(ViewBag.AtList1, "AtributeId", "AtributeName"), " Select a Attribute", new { id="dd", Class = "form-control", title = "priority", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Atribute1)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>    <div class="col-md-6"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;"><b>Attribute 02</b> <b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Atribute2, new SelectList(ViewBag.AtList2, "AtributeId", "AtributeName"), " Select a Attribute", new { id = "dd", Class = "form-control", title = "priority", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Atribute2)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>    <div class="col-md-6"></div>


        <div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;"><b>Attribute 03</b> <b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Atribute3, new SelectList(ViewBag.AtList3, "AtributeId", "AtributeName"), " Select a Attribute", new { id = "dd", Class = "form-control", title = "priority", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Atribute3)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>    <div class="col-md-6"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn" class="btn btn-success" />


    }
```

Comment: You would need to use javascript/jquery to handle each dropdowns `.change()` event and hide the corresponding option in the other dropdowns. Another option would be to use a custom `[NotEqualTo]` attribute so that it displays an error if there are duplicate selections.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks.. :) I tried to do it using javascript. But i failed to develop the correct javascript. Could you pls guide me with examples for both options of you?

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxv3r97c/) and let me know if that's what you want (it not quite right yet but should give you the idea)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yes that's exactly what i want. Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try and let you know the result :)

Comment: There is a problem with it of you then go back and re-select another option but I'll fix that a bit later and post an answer.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, ok... :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, and at the same time pls guide me with your second option also. That will enhance my knowledge. Thanks for helping me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery to hide (or disable) options in the other `<select>`'s to prevent selecting duplicates. Give then a class name (say `class="dd"`) and use the following script

```
var selects = $('.dd');
selects.change(function() {
    // build array of selected option indexes
    var indexes = [];
    $.each(selects, function() {
        indexes.push($(this).children('option:selected').index());
    });
    $.each(selects, function() {
        // get the current selected option index
        var selected = $(this).children('option:selected').index();
        // enable/disable options
        $.each($(this).children('option'), function(index, item) {
            if ($(this).val() && indexes.indexOf(index) > -1 && index != selected) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true); // or $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false); // or $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxv3r97c/2/) for an example

Comment: Thank you... im trying your answer. But im struggling. I have css classes written which is not shown in the above code. I have updated my question to reflect those classes as well.  Could you pls tell me where should i put that class(".dd")?  I tried it like this. In ddls,                 @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Atribute1, new SelectList(ViewBag.AtList1, "AtributeId", "AtributeName"), " Select a Attribute", new { id="dd", Class = "form-control", title = "priority", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" }). And in jquery, var selects = $('#dd');..... But not working. Pls help

Comment: No, it just needs to be `new { @class = "form-control dd", title = "priority", ... }` - you can add as many class names to an element as you like (just separated by a space) but do not add an `id` attribute - this would be invalid html because you cannot have duplicate `id`'s

Comment: Yes that worked..Thank you very much for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about if the **DropDownLists** are dynamically generated by pressing a button?
In my case, this works if I had existing DropDownLists

I generate the below html dynamically every time user presses the + button. But your code does not seem to work.

> My View

```
<div class="form-group" id="parameterTemplate">
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Parameter Code</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.paramCode, ViewBag.AllParameters as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control denyduplicate" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and your java script code as follows

```
var selects = $('.denyduplicate');
selects.change(function () {
    // build array of selected option indexes
    var indexes = [];
    $.each(selects, function () {
        indexes.push($(this).children('option:selected').index());
    });
    $.each(selects, function () {
        var selected = $(this).children('option:selected').index();
        $.each($(this).children('option'), function (index, item) {
            if ($(this).val() && indexes.indexOf(index) > -1 && index != selected) {
                //$(this).hide();
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                //$(this).show();
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```